# Spring Boot keeps asking for login credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Well, I am currently programming on a project with Spring Security where I'd like to register a user in the database.

The proble is, if I vistit the endpoint where the registration should happen I get redirected to the default Login page of Spring Boot which should not happen.

This is my `SecurityConfiguration.java`

```
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePasswd(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

My RestController called `UserController.java` looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/secure/rest")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder =  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @PostMapping("user/register")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        String passwd = user.getPasswordUser();
        String encryptPasswd = passwordEncoder.encode(passwd);
        user.setPasswordUser(encryptPasswd);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "addedUser";
    }

}
```

Comment: try adding in antMatchers("/") code , the /**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.formLogin().disable();
    }
    
}
```